# Add columns to ListBox bound with XmlReader?

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

I have a listbox bound to an XML Reader and when you select different items in the list it populates a separate details pane.  This all works great.   I decided I wanted to add a column to my ListBox to display a couple of the properties inline.  This is where I'm running into trouble.  The [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/general/how-to-specify-the-column-in-a-multi-column-list-box-to-display-to-the-user) say to use `.addItem` but that doesn't work (`'ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'AddItem').  I tried a couple other options too, but no luck.

Here is my code.  How can I simply include `builddate` in the second column of the listbox?

```
public void readRemoteBuildsFile() {
    // Create an XmlUrlResolver
    XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
    resolver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.BuildsURLUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.BuildsURLPassword);


    // Create the reader.
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.XmlResolver = resolver;
   

    // Create the XmlReader object.
    try {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.BuildsURL, settings);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        var dsRemoteBuilds = new DataSet();
        dsRemoteBuilds.ReadXml(reader);
        bs.DataSource = dsRemoteBuilds;
        bs.DataMember = "build";

        lbRemoteBuilds.DataSource = bs;
        lbRemoteBuilds.DisplayMember = "Name";
        lblBuildID.DataBindings.Clear();
        lblBuildID.DataBindings.Add("Text",bs,"id");
        lblBuildDate.DataBindings.Clear();
        lblBuildDate.DataBindings.Add("Text",bs,"builddate");
        lblBuiltBy.DataBindings.Clear();
        lblBuiltBy.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "builtby");
        lblCommit.DataBindings.Clear();
        lblCommit.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "commit");
    } catch (Exception ex)  {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabSettings;
        lblSettingsValidation.Text = "Please enter a valud URL!";
    }

}
```

Comment: listBox1.Items.Add(object)

Comment: I didn't know if you were a novice or had experience so I assumed you were knowledgeable and would ask if you needed clarification.  I don't needed the points and were you post answers people for no good reason gives negative points so I don't respond with answers.  You probably want to create a new instance of the object you are adding to List or the new class you didn't add to the form.

Comment: The .NET ListBox control is very different from the VBA flavor.  Use ListView with View = Details to get multiple columns.  Or DataGridView to get binding support.